# TextView being pushed off the screen by ImageView

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I am having an issue with an ImageView and a TextView. I am having a problem where when I set the layout width and height of the ImageView to "fill_parent", my TextView I would like to have showing under it gets pushed off the screen.

I must have the ImageView to fill the rest of the screen that's why I am using "fill_parent" for the height and width. I've tried using "fill_parent" just for the width and "wrap_content" for the height but then the whole image gets resized(smaller) as if I were using "wrap_content" for both.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_x_high"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</Gallery>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Gallery01" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Textgoeshere"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: umm, how about linear layouts and weights ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align your `TextView` at the bottom of the parent layout , and then put your `ImageView` *below* the `Gallery` , and *above* the `TextView`. this way it will fill the rest of space in your layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_x_high"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</Gallery>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="goes here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textAlignment="gravity" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Gallery01"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1" >
</ImageView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Jack Apply this to ImageView: android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" .

Comment: it's strange , i've tested it and it works for me :), the ImageView is fixed between the Gallery View and the TextView. otherwise , if your ImageView is too big ( in height) , try to use `ScrollView`

Comment: Yes it works now. I released I was being an idiot and applying it to a different project, thanks for the help anyway, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ActivityHome"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
         >
    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     >
    </Gallery>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Textgoeshere"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />    
        </LinearLayout>
```